# Comentar una linea en un fichero.log

Tags: bash, shell, centos

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 !/bin/bash

  while read line;
  do

  echo "$line";
   if[???????]
   fi

  done < /home/javi.log
```

fichero javi.log:

```
#

javi_2223
javi55_555
imp33
imp44
javi32423
javi5646
```

quiero que el script comente las lineas imp33 y imp44 se que se haria con if pero no se que hay que usar para comentarlas...

Quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
#

javi_2223
javi55_555
#imp33
#imp44
javi32423
javi5646
```

si el archivo fuese asi: como seria poniendo el :space no me lo coge

```
javi_2223
javi55_555

#imp33
#imp44

javi32423
javi5646
```

Comment: No necesitas un script de bash para hacer eso, puedes hacerlo usando `sed`. ¿Quieres hacerlo con `sed` muy rápido y con una instrucción de una única línea o un script de bash que vaya línea por línea?

Comment: con una instruccion seria lo suyo si

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Usando `bash`

Para obtener el mejor resultado en `bash` y facilitar agregar nuevos términos te recomiendo hacer uso de `case` en vez de `if` anidados de la siguiente manera:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read limpia espacios por delante y por detrás del texto
while read line
do
  # Dependiendo del contenido de $line ...
  case "$line" in
    imp33|imp44)
      # Si es "imp33" o "imp44" agregamos un # delante
      echo "#${line]"
      ;;
    *)
      # En caso contrario mostramos tal cual la línea
      echo "$line";
      ;;
  esac
done < /home/javi.log
```

## Usando [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

La manera más eficiente de hacer lo que deseas es utilizando la herramienta `sed` usando el siguiente patrón de sustitución:

```
sed -r 's/^(imp33|imp44)$/#\1/' /home/javi.log
```

De toda la funcionalidad que ofrece `sed` he usado la función de "sustitución" (`s` de *substitute*) que tiene el siguiente formato: `s/patrón/sustitución/opciones`. En mi caso no he usado ninguna opción, pero podrías usar `i`, por ejemplo, para que la búsqueda sea insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

En la [versión en línea](https://regex101.com/r/pd1cfX/1) podrás ver una descripción de cómo funciona el patrón y los grupos de captura:

- Inicio de línea `^`.
- Grupo de captura `()`:

  - opción `imp33`.
  - opción `imp44`.
- Fin de línea `$`.

Lo que haya en la línea, en caso de cumplirse el patrón de captura, será sustituido por `#\1` que significa:

- Un símbolo almohadilla `#`.
- Contenido del primer grupo de captura `\1`.

A diferencia de la versión en `bash`, los caracteres en blanco antes y después del texto no son eliminados, por lo que si deseas que el comportamiento sea el mismo deberás usar el siguiente patrón:

```
sed -r 's/^[[:space:]]*(imp33|imp44)[[:space:]]*$/#\1/' /home/javi.log
```

En la [versión en línea](https://regex101.com/r/pd1cfX/3) podrás ver una descripción de cómo funciona el patrón y los grupos de captura:

- Inicio de línea `^`.
- 0 o más caracteres de espacio, tabuladores, etc (`[ \t\r\n\v\f]`).
- Grupo de captura `()`:

  - opción `imp33`.
  - opción `imp44`.
- 0 o más caracteres de espacio, tabuladores, etc (`[ \t\r\n\v\f]`).
- Fin de línea `$`.

Como no se han incluido en el grupo de captura los caracteres en blanco éstos no estarán en la sustitución, que seguirá siendo el carácter almohadilla `#` seguido del grupo de captura.

> Puedes conocer más sobre el funcionamiento de `sed` (gracias a
>   [@Juan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/3092/juan) y [@JackNavaRow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28035/jacknavarow) por la
>   sugerencia) en las siguientes páginas:
>
> - Wikipedia: [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed_(informática)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed_(inform%C3%A1tica))
> - http://www.sromero.org/wiki/linux/aplicaciones/uso_de_sed

Comment: me puedes explicar bien que hace sed ??

Comment: si quisiera eliminar una linea de mi fichero pero existen espacios en blanco al principio y al final como seria ??

Comment: @ortiga , he hecho una edición final a mi respuesta incluyendo una descripción de la funcionalidad de `sed` utilizada, así como el significado del patrón usado. Cuando pase un tiempo borraré mis comentarios en esta respuesta para dejarla limpia. Si no tienes ninguna duda más te recomiendo que también borres tus comentarios de la respuesta. Gracias :)